# Issues with 2 different admin sites in a Django

Tags: django, django-admin

I want to have 2 separate admin sites inside a Django project.

First is default admin
And Second is "coursemanager"
Following code i have added with the help of AdminSite

File Path "cms/courses/admin.py"

```
from courses.models import *
from django.contrib import admin
from django.contrib.admin.sites import AdminSite
from django.contrib.auth.models import User, Group
from django.contrib.auth.admin import UserAdmin, GroupAdmin 

class CourseManager(AdminSite):
    name = 'CourseManager'

course_manager = CourseManager()

class CityAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ['__unicode__', 'status',]
    list_filter = ['status',]
    search_fields = ['title',]

 course_manager.register(City, CityAdmin)
```

"cms/cms/urls.py"

```
from courses.admin import course_manager
urlpatterns = patterns('',    
    url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
    url(r'coursemanager/', include(course_manager.urls)),
)
```

But when i add this http://domain.local/coursemanager/ & http://domain.local/admin/ both panel is working but in http://domain.local/coursemanger/ list register city module but not showing the add or changes links. Event i tried to access links from url but not working. I am checking this as superuser and i have all modules access. But when i change code like bellow

"cms/cms/urls.py"

```
from courses.admin import course_manager
urlpatterns = patterns('',    
    url(r'coursemanager/', include(course_manager.urls)),
    url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
)
```

Then http://domain.local/coursemanager/ working properly and http://domain.local/admin panel is only listing all register admin but not showing the add/change links.

Comment: Your `course_manager` is not instance of `AdminSite`.

Comment: Can you check if it works with `course_manager = AdminSite()`?

Comment: What error do you get when accessing the add/change urls directly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `app_name` of `AdminSite()` is initialized through `AdminSite.__init__()`. You cannot override it by providing class-level variable, thus you were experiencing instance namespace collision and then some `reverse` failure, [here](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/contrib/admin/sites.py#L354), which caused add/change links not showing. Try

```
class CourseManager(AdminSite):
    '...'

course_manager = CourseManager(name='CourseManager')

# or
course_manager = AdminSite(name='CourseManager')
```

Comment: Thanks It's course_manager = CourseManager(name="coursemanager") work for me.